# Properly configure PhpStorm for new Node.js project

Tags: node.js, phpstorm

I'm trying to make a node.js project with PhpStorm and Express framework.

I have set up new project using the template and configure the node interpreter. But in the `package.json` I get these errors.

How can I resolve that?

[image]

Here is my Node.js and NPM configuration

[image]

and when running sample project. i get this socket.io display:

```
GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Ln5CM5C 404 3.831 ms - 1320
```

[image]

The same thing does not happen when using `WebStorm`

Comment: please can you provide your idea.log (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files)? Put it on some file server and provide a link here

Comment: Hi this is my log file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7zeRUVgTo1AVXltZDNfbGh2NjQ

Comment: hi update my question with more detail. All sample project create from template

Comment: socket.io errors have nothing to do with this issue - they are likely a result of your attempts to add socket.io to your app (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44199878/socket-io-with-express-4-15-template-from-webstorm-not-working)

Comment: hi the socket.io i create from WebStorm and no error. This one create new from PhPStorm which does not have socket.io installed

Comment: socket.io is not a part of Express application created from new project template - neither in WebStorm nor in PHPStorm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by **AWS Elastic Beanstalk Integration** plugin - it registers its own schema.json and uses it for JSON files validation. You can disable `AWS Elastic Beanstalk Extensions inspections | AWS Elastic Beanstalk Extensions format violation` inspection in Settings | Editor | Inspections to get rid of the error. 
Please follow https://github.com/viatra2/IDEA-AWS-Elastic-Beanstalk-Integration/issues/40 for updates

Comment: thanks for your help. I follow the link there is no instruction for update. do i need to uninstalled the plugin

Comment: please see updated answer for workaround. You don't necessary need to uninstall the plugin, disabling inspection is enough

Comment: thanks, work fine know. one last question how can you see the error from the log is because of the above plugin?

Comment: from the log I can see what plugins you have installed. So I tried all them and recreated the issue

Comment: Hi lena, seem u are quite familiar with webstorm. Can help me troubleshooting this proplem. Many thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44213145/configure-babel-with-webstorm-to-use-es6-with-webstorm-node-js-project

Comment: see my answer there. Note thaat you issue has absolutely nothing to do with WebStorm, error comes from Node.js interpreter that runs your code

Answer (score 0):

Do you have anything set in File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Schemas and DTDs | JSON Schema?

So far there are no related issues at JetBrains bug tracker: it would worth submitting a similar bug report/question at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB#newissue=yes for developers to take a look into.

Comment: Hi I don't have any JSON Schema. The red alert happen even when start fresh new node.js project