# socket.io with Express 4.15 template from WebStorm not working

Tags: node.js, socket.io, webstorm

I'm trying to setup a `Node.js` server with `socket.io`. I'm using the latest template given by `WebStorm` template.

My step is first add socket.io to my language and framework - Node.js and NPM. Here is my setting

[image]

Then in my "bin/www" I add the below

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server)
```

And add this to bottom of the bin/www file (after server has start listening)

```
io.on("connection",(socket)=>{
  console.log("user connected" + socket.id)
})
```

Then I modify my index.jade as below

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= title
  p Welcome to #{title}

  li what the ul1
  li what the ul2
  script.
    src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"
  script.
    var socket = io();
```

Run the server. visit the page and this is what I get

[image]

I get the error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined
    at localhost/:1
```

Anyone know what wrong with my implementation?

Edit 1: I can get to the socket.io.js by my browser
[image]

Comment: can your browser resolve `socket.io.js` file?

Comment: hi how to check whether browser can resolve or not?

Comment: Hi i have edit the question. my browser can resolve the socket.io.js file

Comment: use `src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"` instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [socket.io - ReferenceError: io is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11995406/socket-io-referenceerror-io-is-not-defined)

Comment: There is a syntax error in my index.jade. should be: script(src="/socket.io/socket.io.js")

Answer (score 0):

I guess your browser can't find the library. You could include it by adding

```
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.1/socket.io.js"
```

to your file.

Comment: Hi I tried to change src="/socket.io/socket.io.js" with src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.1/socket.io.js" but same error

Comment: How about adding the address of your server into the variable of index.jade:
    var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');

Comment: Hi still same error. maybe something wrong with my client implementation

Comment: Hi, I have tried this also but still same error: script.
    src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"

  script.
    var socket = io("http://localhost:3000")

Comment: I tried implement on IOS swift it work. Something wrong with my browser client code

Comment: There is a syntax error in my index.jade. should be: script(src="/socket.io/socket.io.js")